# Building an API around Databricks Notebook

Tags: databricks, databricks-community-edition

I'm very new to the Databricks community platform. I have recently developed an ML model using databricks and would like to productionize it using a Swagger API. I have tried it in bits and pieces but can't figure it out at all. Can someone please give me a flow of how to proceed with this?  Thanks!

Edit:  I would really appreciate a low-code or no-code type solution to this since I'm a data scientist and not really a programmer. Thanks!